# Linq - Getting count from unrelated table

Tags: c#, linq

How to get to execute a `select count(*) from UnrelatedTable where documentLink_Id = x.documentLink_id` and add the resulted count to `totalTimeAccessed`. Both table (`PublishedContent` and `UnrelatedTable` have the `documentLink_id`) in common. Then I would like to select only the rows that have a count greater then 0

```
        var dbData = publishedontext.PublishedContent
                    .Where(x => x.Status > PublishedStatus.Released)
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Title)
                    .Select(x => new DownloadsPerContetnItemReportRows()
                    {
                        title  = x.Title,
                        documentLink_Id = x.DocumentLink_Id,
                        statustatus = x.Status,
                        totalTimeAccessed = "Select count from an unrelated table"
                     }
```

Comment: If they have `docmentLink_Id` in common it isn't unrelated. You could use a `join` or just reference the new table directly. Also why do you say "add": "add the resulted count to totalTimeAccessed". You can't add in a `Select`, you are creating a new object?

Comment: Have you tried this: `totalTimeAccessed = UnrelatedTable.where(r => r.DocumentLink_Id == x.DocumentLink_Id).Count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Following code shall work:

```
totalTimeAccessed = PublishedContent
                    .Join(UnrelatedTable,pc => pc.DocumentLink_Id,
urt => urt.DocumentLink_Id,(pc,urt) => new {pc,urt})
                    .Where(y => pc.Count > 0 && urt.Count > 0)
```

> How it Works

- Joined `PublishedContent` with `UnrelatedTable` on DocumentLink_Id
- On the result checked whether `Count > 0` for both `PublishedContent` and `UnrelatedTable` projections

Would need few modifications based on your specific requirements. In case `Count` refers to the number of rows not a Column as projected, then `Join` will anyway give the matching rows, then we don't need the `Where` clause